# how to format json in angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I want to know how to format my json to have key and value using typescript with Angular framework,

with the current method if I use the keyvalue pipe in my html it will work but I want to format the json.

In my example below I have my Current json and the expected json so that you can see the result I expect and to be as clear as possible being a beginner in the business I wanted to be clear

**Current.json**

```
{
  "url": "url test"
  "flight": [
   [
    "1", 
    "apollo",
    "ariane"
   ],
   [
    "2",
    "Space X",
    "Boca chica"
   ]
  ]
}
```

**expected.json** // this json is what I would like to have

```
{
      "url": "url test"
      "flight": [
       [
        id: "1", 
        name: "apollo",
        rocket:"ariane"
       ],
       [
        id: "2",
        name: "Space X",
        rocket: "falcon 9"
       ]
      ]
    }
```

**ts.file**

```
get() {
 this.service.get().subscribe((data: Interface[])=> {
  this.array = data
 });
```

Comment: `expected.json` is not valid JSON.

Comment: it's not possible to do that? @evolutionxbox

Comment: Not as JSON no. JSON has a specific format to follow. See json.org for more information, or use jsonlint.com to check. --- You may have mean "JS Object", not json?

Answer (score 0):

Your expected Json isn’t valid, if you want property names for those array values you need to make them an object.

```
{
  "url": "url test"
  "flight": [
   {
    id: "1", 
    name: "apollo",
    rocket:"ariane"
   },
   {
    id: "2",
    name: "Space X",
    rocket: "falcon 9"
   }
  ]
 }
```

To get this format from the example you gave you can do this:

```
get() {
  this.service.get().subscribe((data: Interface[])=> {
  data.flight = data.flight.map(f => ({id: f[0], name: f[1], rocket: f[2]}))
  this.array = data
});
```

Comment: That’s still not valid JSON?

Comment: i got this error: property flight does not exist on type 'any[]' why ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code snippet

```
 get() {
   this.service.get().subscribe((data: any)=> {
   data.flight = data.flight.map(f => {
        return {id: f[0], name: f[1], rocket: f[2]}
    })
    this.array = data
    });
```